# Show 2 levels of DXA Navigation

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.7

In DXA 1.7 I would like to show the first level and also second level of navigation items when I am in the second level.  Currently only the sister Navigation Structure Groups of the current Page are shown.  I'm using the OOTB Left Navigation example from the DXA Sample site.

How could I show both the root and second level navigation items when on a second level page?

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK the OOTB Navigation facilities only support sister level of navigation, because the NavigationLinks entity has only one level of Links.

Basically:

- You have to make an extension of the NavigationProvider
- To populate
  your own ExtendedNavigationLinks entity with several levels of links
- And make an extended Navigation view where you can manage several
  levels of navigation

## update

Here is a blog post describing the steps http://www.fecron.com/en/second-level-in-dxa-navigation/

Comment: Wow - sounds like quite a few steps!  Any blog articles or code samples out there to demonstrate how?

Comment: Added Rauls blog post, excellent work!